# recursively call a program to run on each subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, directory-structure

I have a program which does something like

```
#!bin/bash

cd $1

tree $1
```

Where I run:

```
myprogram.sh subdir1
```

Where `subdir1` is a subdirectory of `dir` I however have `subdir1, subdir2, subdir3... subdirN` within `dir`.

How can I tell my program to run on every sub directory of `dir`? Obviously my program doe not just run `tree` but just to denote I pass a subdirectory through the command line, of which my program uses the subdirectory name for a numer of processes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`. For example `find $1 -type d` will return a list of all directories under `$1`, recursing as needed.

You can use it before your script with `xargs` or `exec`:

```
find DIR -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 thescript.sh
```

or

```
find DIR -type d -exec thescript.sh {} \;
```

Both of the above are safe for strangely named directories.

If you want to use `find` inside your script **and no directory names contain newlines**, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -type d| IFS='' while read d; do
   pushd "$d" #like cd, but remembers where you came from

   tree "$d"; #<-- your code here

   popd #go back to starting point
done
```

If you only want direct subdirectories of the starting point, try adding `-depth 1` in the argument list to `find` in the above examples.